# can't telnet on port 5433 on localhost after iptables stop

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to do a `telnet localhost 5433` on my RHEL box but I get a connection refused error. I did a `service iptables stop` but am still getting the same error. Where else do I need to look to allow the the port 5433 to be open?

EDIT:

when I do a netstat -atpn...vertica is on and listening it looks like:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.205.119.236:4803         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13707/spread
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5444                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13442/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42092               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1091/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1069/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2738                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1586/./bin/discagnt
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1291/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8089                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      16411/splunkd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59097               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13717/vertica-udx-z
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13713/vertica
```

Comment: What is supposed to be running on that port? I'm afraid it isn't running, whatever it is.

Comment: try netstat -an from your redhat, do you see any line with *.5433 LISTEN ?

Comment: don't see a *.5433 but I do see `0.0.0.0:5433` LISTEN...made an edit to show netstat as well...

Comment: What version of RHEL?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your `telnet` command, you see a few lines of output, which describes where it tries to connect actually. Normally `localhost` resolves to both ::1 and 127.0.0.1, but it's possible that on your system the IPv4 address is missing, and that's why your `telnet` is failing. You can try connecting explicitly on the IPv4 loopback via the following command: `telnet 0 5433` (`0` is a nice shorthand for an IPv4 loopback address). If this still fails, you should check if the `iptables` rules are in fact emptied, by running `for i in mangle table nat; do iptables -L -vn -t $i; done`. If this still doesn't help, and your system is otherwise idle, you can try comparing `netstat -s` outputs before and after trying to connect, to see if it sheds any more light on your issue.